# Parse substring of particular date format from string

Tags: java

Give a String of a date format, I'd like to check if the string contains the date format. If it does, I'd like to parse the value from that string.

Example:

```
 String format = "yyyyMMddHHmm";
 String matchedString = "abcdefg201504030435abcdefg";
 String unmatchedString = "abcdefg201504abcdefg";
```

I'm trying to design a method that would return "201504030435" for matchedString, and null for unmatchedString.

I've used DateTimeFormatter for parsing an exact string, but I've never extracted a substring of a known format.

I know this could be done with a RegEx, but the goal is attempt to do this with the `format` so that the String could be parsed using a `DateTimeFormatter` of the same format.

Comment: Sorry, that goal is unobtainable. `DateTimeFormatter` is too rigid to handle that, and it is `final`, so you can't even extend it. Your idea of using regex is likely the best choice.

Comment: Is it just this: "201504030435" format, or you are looking at multiple the formats?

Comment: @HarshalParekh - the intention is for the format to be dynamic - meaning that we would have many different formats being supported.

Comment: In this case, I think writing multiple RegEx is the only solution. Pass the string through all the Regular Expressions to find the one that matches.